# How do I compare 2 fields and return the lowest value of each record?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm slowly learning access to make a database of products and suppliers for my parents' business. What i've got is a table of products indexed by our product reference and 2 more tables for 2 different suppliers that contains the suppliers product reference and price that links with our reference.

I've made a query that performs a left outer join such that it returns a table of our products with each supplier's reference and price, i.e:

> Ref | Product Name | Supplier 1 Ref |
>   Supplier 1 Price | Supplier 2 Ref |
>   Supplier 2 Price

Here's the query I used:

```
SELECT Catalog.Ref, Catalog.[Product Name], Catalog.Price, 
    [D Products].[Supplier Ref], [D Products].Cost, 
    [GS Products].[Supplier Ref], [GS Products].Cost

FROM ([Catalog] LEFT JOIN [D Products] ON Catalog.Ref = [D Products].Ref)

LEFT JOIN [GS Products] ON Catalog.Ref = [GS Products].Ref;
```

Not all products are available from both suppliers, hence the outer join.

What I want to do (with a query?) is to take the table produced by the query above and simply show the product reference, cheapest supplier reference and cheapest supplier price, i.e:

> Ref | Cheapest Suppplier Ref |
>   Cheapest Supplier Price

Unfortunately my SQL knowledge isn't quite good enough to figure this out, but if anyone can help i'd really appreciate it.

Thanks, Rob

Comment: Can you show us the query that produces the top result - so that we can modify appropriately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please consider a single table to hold your supplier product cost data.  With this sample product_catalog data:

```
product_id product_name price
         1 foo              5
         2 bar             10
         3 baz             15
```

The suppliers table might look like this:

```
supplier_id product_id cost
D                    1 2.5
D                    2 7.5
GS                   1 2.75
GS                   3 10
```

Then a GROUP BY query, qryLowestPrice, will show you the lowest cost for each product:

```
SELECT s.product_id, Min(s.cost) AS MinOfcost
FROM suppliers AS s
GROUP BY s.product_id;
```

You can then use qryLowestPrice in another query to pull in the other information (product_name and supplier_id) you want:

```
SELECT q.product_id, p.product_name, p.price, s.supplier_id, s.cost
FROM
    (qryLowestPrice AS q
    INNER JOIN product_catalog AS p
    ON q.product_id = p.product_id)
    INNER JOIN suppliers AS s
    ON (q.MinOfcost = s.cost) AND (q.product_id = s.product_id);
```

This is the output from that second query based on the sample data above:

```
product_id product_name price supplier_id cost
         1 foo              5 D           2.5
         2 bar             10 D           7.5
         3 baz             15 GS          10
```

Comment: That works brilliantly mate thank you ever so much, you've saved me so much head scratching!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT  Catalog.Ref, 
        Catalog.[Product Name], 
        Catalog.Price, 
        [D Products].[Supplier Ref], 
        [D Products].Cost, 
        [GS Products].[Supplier Ref], 
        [GS Products].Cost,
        iif ([D Products].Cost < [GS Products].Cost, [D Products].[Supplier Ref], [GS Products].[Supplier Ref]) AS CheapestSupplier,
        iif ([D Products].Cost < [GS Products].Cost, [D Products].Cost, [GS Products].Cost) AS CheapestSupplierPrice
FROM (  [Catalog] LEFT JOIN 
        [D Products] ON Catalog.Ref = [D Products].Ref) LEFT JOIN 
        [GS Products] ON Catalog.Ref = [GS Products].Ref;
```

Comment: That seems to work well thank you John, I noticed however the two cheapest columns will only return the values if the product exists in [GS Products], eg if the product just available in the [D Products] table it wont show anything in the cheapest columns, but it does work if it's just available in the [GS Products] table or both tables. Any suggestions?

Comment: I got it to work using nested iif's to check each field for null then run the price comparison, Thanks John

Comment: I was just about to answer, MSSQL has a function called ISNULL(column, value) where column is your column, and value is the value you want returned if its null. In access I think it is nz(column,value). Basically if the column is null then return value else return column.

Comment: If D and GS both offer the same cost for a given product, the query will return the GS cost.  If D offers a product that GS does not, the query will return the GS cost (Null).  If @BigRob ever needs to cope with more than 2 suppliers, the IIf() logic will become more challenging.

Comment: In Access/Jet/ACE Nz() is the equivalent of SQL Server IsNull().

Answer (score 0):

I think that you'll want to have the corresponding Supplier Ref for the lowest price. It can be done with a `CASE WHEN` construct :

```
CASE WHEN expression THEN true_part ELSE false_part END
```

It'll be :

```
SELECT Ref,
  CASE WHEN Supplier1Price < Supplier2Price THEN Supplier1Ref ELSE Supplier2Ref END AS "Cheapest Supplier Ref",
  CASE WHEN Supplier1Price < Supplier2Price THEN Supplier1Price ELSE Supplier2Price END AS "Cheapest Supplier Price"
```

As you're using Access, the syntax is a bit different. You can use the function `IIF(condition, true_part, false_part)`.

```
SELECT Ref,
  IIF(Supplier1Price < Supplier2Price, Supplier1Ref, Supplier2Ref) AS "Cheapest Supplier Ref",
  IIF(Supplier1Price < Supplier2Price, Supplier1Price, Supplier2Price) AS "Cheapest Supplier Price"
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer mate, what you've put makes sense to me but access doesn't like my syntax:
SELECT [Products Query].[Ref],
CASE
WHEN [GS Products].[Cost] < [D Products].[Cost] 
THEN [GS Products].[Supplier Ref] 
ELSE [D Products].[Supplier Ref]
END AS "Cheapest Supplier Ref",
MIN([GS Products].Cost, [D Products].Cost) AS "Cheapest Supplier Price"

Comment: In Access, you have to use `IIF`. I've updated my reponse with a sample

Comment: Thanks again for your response bud but i'm still having some trouble with Access, now it's returning 'wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression 'MIN([GS Products].Cost, [D Products].Cost)

Comment: You're right, I misuse the `Min` function, as it's an aggregator one. Use the same construct as the other with an `IIF`

Comment: You might have to convert null to as value. Try the `COALESCE(field, default_value)` or `ISNULL(field, default_value)` to replace the value in field by default_value when field is null